I am getting an error when adding razor view in .net 6 core project
I am getting the following error when adding a view after the update. I didn't use bootstrap in my project and I hadn't updated the package yet.
I tried to update the project file but it didn't work.I cannot upgrade the design package.

The question you asked and the information you provided are not complete. I suggest you visit this link to learn how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
